# How To Make Text Not Wrap

Tags: html, css

Hello I am currently trying to place a piece of text in the centre of my div and make it not wrap, I have got it not to wrap but now the ends of the text goes off my screen!

```css
#title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 50px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="title">This is my text</h1>
```

Comment: You might want to include an example that actually exhibits the issue you're facing and you should also clarify what output you expect. If text doesn't wrap and it's too long for the container in which it's defined, it overflows as you're seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to wrap the text, you have to do something else like **ellipsis**(3 dots at the end), just set the '**width**' of the element and set '**text-overflow**' to 'ellipsis'.

```css
#title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 50px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  width:50%;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="title">This is my text</h1>
```